# Django ModelForm: Excluding required field from ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

Let's say I've got a bunch of models M_1, ..., M_n, ..., M_2n, so there are 2n models in total. Each of the first n models has a (required) foreign key referencing a model of the last n models. So: say that model M_x has a (required) foreign key FK_x to the model M_2x, where 1 <= x <= n.

For each model M_x (1 <= x <= n) I now like to have a model form MF_x. I require that MF_x excludes the foreign key FK_x, such that FK_x does not show up in the form. Since FK_x is a required field though, I require that the field is provided on form instantiation like this:

```
model_2x_instance = M_2x.objects.create(**some_data)
model_x_instance = M_x(FK_x=model_2x_instance, ...)
form_x_instance = MF_x(instance=model_x_instance)
```

The __init__ of MF_x then does the following to check that the 'instance' argument is given and has the foreign key FK_x to the model M_2x set:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)

  if not instance:
    raise InstanceRequiredError

  if not hasattr(instance, 'FK_x') or not instance.FK_x:
    raise ForeignKeyRequiredError

  ...
```

The clean method of MF_x then injects the excluded FK_x back into the cleaned_data dictionary, such that the form can create/modify the M_x instance:

```
def clean(self):
  self.cleaned_data.update(FK_x=self.instance.FK_x)
  return super(...).clean()
```

The problem now is, that I don't like to repeat that two code snippets for each of those model forms. But I can't think of a neat way to refactor this such that everything is DRY.

If *I could* write something like this:

```
class Meta:
  exclude_but_require_and_inject_later = 'FK_x'
```

a common base class for all the model forms MF_x (1 <= x <= n) *could* apply the code snippets above for every such excluded field. But it's (reasonably) not possible to extend the Meta class with own keywords.

Comment: Why do this in form classes at all? It seems to me the form objects should just handle form stuff; do all the FK stuff somewhere else (in the view that handles the forms, a utility called by the view, etc).

Comment: The FK is a field of the ModelForm so the FK is model stuff. The form excludes the FK and I now require a form that makes sure that an instance with the FK set is given and that puts the FK back to cleaned_data on clean.

Comment: Again: you're doing consistency logic in your form classes. That's going to be ugly no matter what way you slice it. Instead of trying to make this work, I think you should *not* do this, and instead handle consistency logic somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Forms are intended to encapsulate consistency checks. Each clean_field and the clean method checks field consistency.

Comment: Form code should be related to forms. Your FKs never get rendered, never get POSTed, just get passed to `__init__` and injected in `.clean()`. There's no reason for that. Separate your concerns. Just have your forms concerned with validating the form, and handle your model consistency logic elsewhere.